# Solve a simple system of differential inequalities

Tags: inequalities, differentials, free-wolfram-engine

I would want to use WolframEngine's API to compute motion path equations. For example, a uniform motion's system of equations gives a path equation:

```
In = DSolve[{s'[t] == v[t], v'[t] == a, s[0] == b, v[0] == c}, {s[t], v[t]}, t]

                2 b + 2 c t + a t
Out = {{s[t] -> ------------------, v[t] -> c + a t}}
                       2
```

Can I somehow obtain a solution if `v'[t] == a` is replaced by `v'[t] <= a`? I know that in this particular case, I can just convert the answer to

```
         2 b + 2 c t + a t
s[t] <= ------------------, v[t] <= c + a t
                2
```

but is it possible to make WolframEngine solve systems like that?

Comment: Just assume $aa \le a$ and `DSolve[{s'[t] == v[t], v'[t] == aa, s[0] == b, v[0] == c}, {s[t], v[t]}, t]`

Comment: `Assuming[aa < a, DSolve[ ... ]]` gives the same answer as above, `DSolve[..., Assumptions -> aa < a] gives an error, `Assuming[aa < a, DSolveValue[ ... ]]` gives only right-hand sides of the solutions